How do I make a USB, bootable, of Hirens Boot CD, https://www.hirensbootcd.org/, on my ubuntu 24.10?
I'll need some detailed explaining, because of my former seaches on the web, all I got was a faulty boot, he he, I learned a lot.
Before one could do it w the make a bootable usb, which comes with ubuntu?, but more restrictions about the input iso, so it does not stay as an input iso, it blanks the option/choice.
I think a lot of ppl could need this, because I could not find a good guide, at least for me, I used a bit of time to get an answer, which didn't get a solution.
And maybe someone could explain the prosess, to make ANY iso into a bootable usb.
To get a neighbour to do it with Window$, is for me not an option aka a big loss.

This question is similar to: How to create a bootable Clonezilla USB that works?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

A solution to consider is ventoy USB installation Should work just as well on 24.10
